# Remove near duplicate rows and keep the highest scoring row

Tags: r, hough-transform

I have a data frame containing three variables: `theta`, `rho` and `score`. I would like to filter out rows that are 'almost' duplicate.

For example: if the value of `theta` is in an interval of 10 **and** `rho` in an interval of 15 from another row, they can be assumed to be duplicates. I then want to remove the row with the lowest `score` of the two duplicates.

What I am thinking of, is first `arrange()` the dataframe by `score` (descending), then create a `for()` loop. Then I create a vector `lines` and add a row to `lines` when no duplicate is already present.

I would really like to avoid using a `for()` loop, since the dataframe is big (over 40000 rows) and such loops can be slow. I have no clue on how to achieve this by using for example `dplyr`.

A sample of the data:

`> dput(head(df %>% arrange(desc(score)), 1000))`

```
structure(list(theta = c(112.727272727111, 294.545454545031, 
298.18181818139, 294.545454545031, 116.363636363469, 116.363636363469, 
116.363636363469, 112.727272727111, 294.545454545031, 298.18181818139, 
112.727272727111, 119.999999999828, 116.363636363469, 112.727272727111, 
294.545454545031, 298.18181818139, 294.545454545031, 301.818181817748, 
294.545454545031, 112.727272727111, 298.18181818139, 116.363636363469, 
290.909090908673, 290.909090908673, 116.363636363469, 116.363636363469, 
112.727272727111, 298.18181818139, 116.363636363469, 294.545454545031, 
119.999999999828, 298.18181818139, 298.18181818139, 119.999999999828, 
116.363636363469, 287.272727272315, 294.545454545031, 116.363636363469, 
112.727272727111, 112.727272727111, 101.818181818036, 298.18181818139, 
290.909090908673, 116.363636363469, 119.999999999828, 298.18181818139, 
298.18181818139, 290.909090908673, 109.090909090752, 290.909090908673, 
294.545454545031, 109.090909090752, 290.909090908673, 119.999999999828, 
290.909090908673, 109.090909090752, 112.727272727111, 301.818181817748, 
290.909090908673, 116.363636363469, 101.818181818036, 109.090909090752, 
109.090909090752, 116.363636363469, 287.272727272315, 87.2727272726019, 
119.999999999828, 112.727272727111, 301.818181817748, 119.999999999828, 
119.999999999828, 83.6363636362435, 109.090909090752, 290.909090908673, 
109.090909090752, 119.999999999828, 301.818181817748, 116.363636363469, 
109.090909090752, 109.090909090752, 283.636363635956, 290.909090908673, 
330.909090908615, 109.090909090752, 298.18181818139, 301.818181817748, 
116.363636363469, 105.454545454394, 29.0909090908673, 101.818181818036, 
105.454545454394, 119.999999999828, 290.909090908673, 116.363636363469, 
112.727272727111, 109.090909090752, 269.090909090522, 105.454545454394, 
109.090909090752, 290.909090908673, 269.090909090522, 301.818181817748, 
301.818181817748, 305.454545454107, 272.727272726881, 283.636363635956, 
87.2727272726019, 290.909090908673, 116.363636363469, 301.818181817748, 
290.909090908673, 294.545454545031, 239.999999999655, 105.454545454394, 
119.999999999828, 301.818181817748, 116.363636363469, 290.909090908673, 
83.6363636362435, 327.272727272257, 283.636363635956, 283.636363635956, 
254.545454545089, 287.272727272315, 258.181818181447, 119.999999999828, 
298.18181818139, 261.818181817806, 87.2727272726019, 290.909090908673, 
210.909090908788, 290.909090908673, 105.454545454394, 327.272727272257, 
319.99999999954, 65.4545454544514, 287.272727272315, 119.999999999828, 
283.636363635956, 287.272727272315, 298.18181818139, 105.454545454394, 
279.999999999598, 272.727272726881, 305.454545454107, 287.272727272315, 
87.2727272726019, 43.6363636363009, 87.2727272726019, 43.6363636363009, 
287.272727272315, 138.18181818162, 119.999999999828, 309.090909090465, 
7.27272727271682, 90.9090909089603, 290.909090908673, 301.818181817748, 
39.9999999999425, 32.7272727272257, 109.090909090752, 116.363636363469, 
279.999999999598, 105.454545454394, 119.999999999828, 276.363636363239, 
305.454545454107, 301.818181817748, 101.818181818036, 218.181818181505, 
272.727272726881, 272.727272726881, 301.818181817748, 309.090909090465, 
279.999999999598, 254.545454545089, 243.636363636014, 229.09090909058, 
32.7272727272257, 199.999999999713, 254.545454545089, 272.727272726881, 
294.545454545031, 301.818181817748, 283.636363635956, 123.636363636186, 
7.27272727271682, 287.272727272315, 87.2727272726019, 254.545454545089, 
283.636363635956, 305.454545454107, 65.4545454544514, 330.909090908615, 
119.999999999828, 123.636363636186, 283.636363635956, 72.7272727271682, 
76.3636363635266, 109.090909090752), rho = c(41.0836002377417, 
-45.0465084042093, -37.9532480936103, -43.044158227946, 30.9877673496997, 
35.9936427903578, 32.9901175259629, 39.0812500614784, -46.0476834923408, 
-29.9438473885574, 40.0824251496101, 23.8936399748773, 26.9830669971733, 
42.0847753258733, -42.0429831398144, -36.9520730054787, -41.0418080516828, 
-26.8536397978266, -44.0453333160777, 43.0859504140049, -35.950897917347, 
28.9854171734365, -50.1354285011879, -51.1366035893195, 34.9924677022261, 
27.9842420853049, 46.0894756783997, -34.9497228292154, 25.9818919090416, 
-48.0500336686041, 13.8818890935612, -38.9544231817418, -40.9567733580051, 
24.8948150630089, 29.9865922615681, -60.2278996099466, -47.0488585804724, 
33.9912926140945, 37.0788998852153, 38.0800749733469, 85.3732907252706, 
-33.9485477410838, -54.1401288537143, 31.9889424378313, 16.885414357956, 
-32.9473726529522, -31.9461975648206, -62.1495295587672, 55.18197515857, 
-48.1330783249247, -49.0512087567357, 64.1925509517545, -52.1377786774511, 
26.8971652392721, -49.1342534130563, 48.1737495416487, 44.0871255021365, 
-27.8548148859583, -59.1460042943724, 24.98071682091, 66.3509640507701, 
45.1702242772539, 49.1749246297804, 22.9783666446468, -82.253751548842, 
120.686872286734, 12.8807140054296, 48.0918258546629, -21.8477643571686, 
10.8783638291664, 14.8830641816928, 131.758025665537, 53.1796249823068, 
-60.147179382504, 60.1878505992281, 8.87601365290313, -13.8383636521157, 
23.9795417327784, 47.1725744535171, 57.1843253348332, -72.3200714342242, 
-53.1389537655828, 91.9951732050117, 40.1643488365959, -27.9414972122942, 
-22.8489394453002, 21.9771915565152, 50.2555352073846, 237.136779368164, 
55.3380380813223, 70.2790369700168, 21.8912897986141, -67.1554049994253, 
20.9760164683836, 45.0883005902681, 52.1784498941752, -119.654988035104, 
62.2696362649639, 50.176099717912, -57.1436541181092, -178.724318234869, 
-18.8442390927738, -33.8618654147479, -0.73510658654489, -110.579957573771, 
-90.3412230205932, 99.6621954359703, -72.1612804400833, 36.9948178784894, 
-29.8571650622215, -65.1530548231621, -51.0535589329989, -167.060502489566, 
48.2531850311214, 25.8959901511405, -31.8595152384847, 19.974841380252, 
-58.1448292062408, 183.819130248381, 62.8740557236012, -91.3423981087248, 
-89.3400479324616, -143.897766031004, -59.226724521815, -169.881611464456, 
29.900690503667, -42.9591235342683, -150.80781195583, 111.67629649355, 
-42.126027796135, -244.156619676724, -68.1565800875569, 82.2931380275962, 
72.8858066049173, 45.6767233434207, 169.021874270401, -81.2525764607104, 
20.8901147104825, -98.3506237256461, -61.2290746980781, -39.9555982698734, 
54.260235559911, -112.44218190202, -119.590533366955, -10.746857467861, 
-50.2161487286305, 132.700973344313, 237.190546304581, 121.688047374866, 
232.184670863923, -52.2184989048937, -53.6413626642005, 15.8842392698244, 
20.3784955094908, 211.865903318108, 154.664384192041, -63.1507046468988, 
-28.8559899740899, 236.184390219668, 239.160977781544, 46.1713993653855, 
17.9724912039888, -70.3928282004921, 53.2590604717795, 11.879538917298, 
-127.531648913209, 0.266068501586671, -3.82661277079962, 102.393267223508, 
-228.170369542773, -123.595233719481, -104.572907044981, -25.852464709695, 
1.35616883499019, -60.3810773191761, -248.019975196692, -210.085066262338, 
-240.190868827689, 237.158627605281, -218.036119344605, -200.964746054506, 
-122.59405863135, -56.0594343736569, -20.846589269037, -93.344748284988, 
3.78276259922932, 162.80832399966, -54.2208490811569, 175.751502133973, 
-180.941244291874, -92.3435731968564, 9.27664429477117, 170.023049358533, 
84.9869475880904, 18.8877645342192, -2.22428792956033, -63.3094956410397, 
127.900471265421, 127.856219152482, 32.154948131543), score = c(381.781574988754, 
376.867929304018, 364.626105647432, 299.691569724508, 294.231324378097, 
293.952772362833, 283.460261504884, 282.056364048014, 267.206929374373, 
261.168680064558, 252.414542012009, 237.042185845451, 234.078052148331, 
229.606725420143, 216.324860493748, 215.558533330939, 210.842537314501, 
208.368243554419, 205.181406815045, 204.261096051397, 197.324237979165, 
189.521926303097, 188.969964944608, 186.638575913254, 185.140684108428, 
183.377726563851, 182.124986813598, 182.045260423294, 181.846212597077, 
180.37944359477, 178.789891727661, 176.192227059953, 175.964328485497, 
174.846290171029, 171.988837570636, 169.019640895807, 167.9119495256, 
167.813177641545, 163.691114744162, 163.450749580731, 162.451649238718, 
158.403998247919, 156.155648844112, 153.590137368734, 152.769361891751, 
152.520713855705, 151.655777652606, 149.409331820614, 146.472014630364, 
146.115633442028, 146.052498649575, 135.864783446716, 134.768563651941, 
132.404742423211, 131.51576293036, 130.82284429468, 130.788174510703, 
128.424175293775, 126.128019200478, 124.336645293274, 123.597399463198, 
121.646401630518, 120.301723278087, 114.561484716175, 114.48553813731, 
113.216562649051, 112.226621711484, 111.461463120992, 110.013083445497, 
109.576273588556, 109.137012441314, 106.688602963489, 106.400626093183, 
106.133536519578, 105.777492905745, 105.688442177713, 104.456641874613, 
104.433669269611, 103.314623077763, 102.259746393435, 102.17938530452, 
101.670539083899, 100.452688050998, 99.02520484887, 98.4335113782726, 
98.0429505018094, 97.4402598820602, 95.7587658236876, 95.2950696240885, 
94.9586058341693, 94.3866751251166, 94.3158182244223, 93.7565070140147, 
92.127262977829, 91.8548747919413, 91.4386321895478, 91.3768416587042, 
91.3010019223121, 91.1345447367969, 90.3128424524546, 89.0661383970599, 
89.0055316281083, 88.6971624966804, 87.7983886555544, 87.0306396564274, 
85.9204774141763, 85.7965196497019, 85.3142922578242, 84.8425562837965, 
84.3735638666951, 83.9731763120239, 82.7466784247688, 82.6092763898421, 
82.0587829926224, 81.6777059131652, 81.4293731744454, 80.8438294356826, 
80.8211826121344, 80.6709609724947, 80.6465532824821, 80.5178349938752, 
80.1999503837411, 80.1719116395444, 79.8942969725428, 79.7436418638969, 
79.7277805289744, 79.70684435464, 79.6847128002474, 79.6806763649338, 
79.1777583656981, 78.6352312634342, 78.6274361426217, 78.5428920502696, 
77.7337176668642, 76.7946629291839, 76.4466244176081, 76.1485811758828, 
75.7612036684239, 75.2150823543861, 75.0345313303339, 74.8673067291731, 
74.8517038879151, 74.7508858198005, 74.5527292285188, 74.5267512278319, 
74.5227005364768, 74.4094234954551, 74.3674893962718, 74.3219691212919, 
73.8157794991736, 73.2286453984909, 73.222367796426, 72.8313773620846, 
72.7470649807689, 72.5137753468749, 72.5132078673106, 72.5025730252246, 
72.4385676060556, 72.1537622540259, 71.9425613728977, 71.6928128941157, 
71.5832397214361, 71.5322922095169, 71.2972159994947, 71.1810801604769, 
71.1642327631934, 71.076532336903, 71.0515945984565, 70.8404496937105, 
70.6690362061286, 70.3221433523102, 70.3120255269573, 70.3017098533045, 
70.265603928538, 70.2477297855539, 69.8757560784155, 69.8418754120254, 
69.7502537524278, 69.6096619396855, 69.0774383151024, 69.0200227396948, 
69.0172508598699, 68.9528342390049, 68.9023657817845, 68.5773542159423, 
68.305995695382, 68.1327451195585, 67.9244802616279, 67.6804525353541, 
67.5989028542724, 67.5963786570388, 67.4025447304631, 67.3888299703067, 
67.0351641892631, 66.9494920024158, 66.2982455895387, 66.2033914475987, 
66.0129552398745, 65.9579581030256, 65.6753707562488)), row.names = c(NA, 
200L), class = "data.frame")
```

Sidenote: The data is obtained from using a Hough transform on an image.

**EDIT:** Example data:

```
> df
  theta rho score
1    10  10   200
2    15  15   150
3    16  16   145
4    25  25   100
5    50  50    50
6    60  60    40
7    70  70    20
8    75  75     5
9   110 110   100
```

Desired output:

```
> df
  theta rho score
1    10  10   200
2    50  50    50
3   110 110   100
```

**For my actual data, an interval of 8 around `theta` and 10 around `rho` is used**

Comment: if A=10, B=20 and C=30, B is within 10 of A, and C is within 10 of B. Should B and C both be marked as 'duplicate'? Or should A and C be marked as duplicate of B, or... or... ?  It would help if you posted your desired output.

Comment: Yes on the first question. A, B and C will be duplicates and I would like to keep only one of those three. I will try to create an example with desired output in a bit.

Comment: Edited my question to add an example with desired output. @Wimpel

Comment: I don't get your output. Why is the line 4 removed ? Line 2 is removed, and then line 3 because between line 1 and 3 `theta` is in an interval of 10 and `rho` in 15. So you have line 1, 4 and 5 now. And these two successive rows don't fulfill the conditions, so why is 4 removed ?

Comment: @denis because line 4 is a duplicate of line 3, so should also be removed.

Comment: If you have a lot of data within a limited parameter space, it is possible that all your data will consist of overlapping duplicates, and following your logic, you will end up with one data point!   Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: @Knackiedoo yes that could be (and probably is) the case. Obviously I do not want that. But I have no clue on how I CAN do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a tidyverse approach

**sample data for desired output**

```
df <- read.table(text="id theta rho score
1    10  10   200
                 2    15  15   150
                 3    16  16   145
                 4    25  25   100
                 5    50  50    50
                 6    60  60    40
                 7    70  70    20
                 8    75  75     5
                 9   110 110   100", header = TRUE)
```

**code**

```
library( tidyverse )

df %>%
  #first, arrange by theta
  arrange( theta ) %>%
  #mark rows with theta <=10 of next row
  mutate( theta_mark = if_else( abs( theta - lag(theta) ) <= 10, 1, 0 ) ) %>%
  #second, arrange by rho
  arrange( rho ) %>%
  #mark rows with rho <=15 of next row
  mutate( rho_mark = if_else( abs( rho - lag(rho) ) <= 15, 1, 0 ) ) %>%
  #replace NA's with 0
  replace_na( list( theta_mark = 0, rho_mark = 0 ) ) %>%
  #filter all unwanted rows
  filter( theta_mark == 0 & rho_mark == 0 ) %>%
  #drop unwanted columns
  select( -theta_mark, -rho_mark )
```

**output**

```
#   id theta rho score
# 1  1    10  10   200
# 2  5    50  50    50
# 3  9   110 110   100
```

Comment: Work with the example data, but does not with my actual data. Literally every row is given value 1 for `theta_mark` and `rho_mark`.

Answer (score 1):

With reference to my comment about overlapping duplicates, you could do this iteratively, removing the duplicates of the highest scoring point, then repeating with the next highest scoring of the remaining points etc.  The following code should do that for you, and in your posted data set, this leaves 27 points.  Although inefficient, a loop is the easiest way I could think of for a quick answer.  I am sure it is possible to do this without a loop, which you would need if you had tens of millions of points, but really should not be necessary in this case.

```
df1 <- df
thetaInterval <- 8
rhoInterval <- 10
i <- 0
while(i < nrow(df1)){
  i <- i + 1
  df1 <- df1[order(df1$score, decreasing = TRUE), ]
  dups <- abs(df1$theta - df1$theta[i]) <= 8 &
    abs(df1$rho - df1$rho[i]) <= 10
  df1 <- df1[!dups, ]
}
```

Comment: Yeah I already considered a loop, see my question. This code takes me about 4 seconds to complete. This is WAY too long for what I want it to be. That is why I asked for a solution without a loop.